# ElasticSearch - Insert to index with forward slash using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am currently investigating using ElasticSearch. I have been following their guides and doing some testing using the dev tools on Kibana and it seems simple enough.

Using the REST API I can index a document by sending a POST request to `/recipes`, and I can also index it by sending it to `/recipes/cakes`, but I am now having trouble replicating this behaviour via the NEST client.

I am attempting to do a bulk insert and it works fine if I just specify `recipes`

`client.IndexMany(docs, "/recipes");`

It seems to me it would make sense to be able to then also do:

`client.IndexMany(docs, "/recipes/cakes");`

However this throws an error: `Invalid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /recipes%2Fcakes/_bulk`

I can see the issue is because it is url encoding the `/`, so what is the correct way to use an index with a `/` in it? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was mistaken about how these paths work, I thought you could have several levels such as `/recipes/cakes/chocolate` but this would actually be to insert a document with an index `recipes`, type `cakes` and id of `chocolate`.

As such I can achieve what I was trying to above by using the next parameter in the IndexMany method (`TypeName type`):

`client.IndexMany(docs, "recipes", "cakes");`

Comment: Also take a look at using `DefaultMappingFor<T>` conventions within NEST such that say for a `Cake` POCO type, it will default to using the `"recipes"` index and `"cake"` type (I would recommend singular for type): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html#_options_on_connectionsettings and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index-name-inference.html

Comment: @RussCam thanks for the suggestion, although it seems they intend to remove types altogether: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html So I guess the way to do it would be either have an index for each type of recipe or just have 1 recipes index and have a custom "type" field on each document.

Comment: types are going away altogether in 7.x, and 6.x allows only a single type per index. Whether to use one index or many, some things to consider: (1) each index requires resources, or more accurately, each shard requires resources. Depending on number of docs, a single shard may be sufficient. (2) if recipes share common fields that you wish to search in the same way, then a single index and single POCO with a discriminating field may be sufficient.